# Do professional front end developers use any UI software or they just code in a text editor?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web-frontend, visual-web-developer

I'm wondering if there is some software that makes creating websites easier like a "Photoshop" with buttons and menus for front-end development. Or do people just code the whole thing in a text editor?

I'm asking because I came across a video about "Webflow" and it seems like building a website using tools like this would be much faster for professionals than coding it.

Do professionals use any tools like this?  If so which are the most popular?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yJ3vsAnbi_o

Many thanks!

Comment: Adobe dreamware is also an option. 
https://www.adobe.com/products/dreamweaver.html
But as a developer I would use a nice IDE like VS code and write all my html using advance css framework to have full control of my website.

Comment: The ones I know just use a good IDE (Integrated development environment), which is similar to a text editor,but with a lot clever functions / shortcuts / search options etc...

Comment: Sort of both.  Most work is done in text editors, but a good UI person also works with frameworks, graphics libraries, style processors, etc. to improve and standardize their workflow, and they need a solid background in graphic design for when aspects of a UI may call for icons, logos, stock images, etc.  What tools are popular will depend a lot on what your development environment is (Web, Windows, Mac, Android, etc.)

Comment: I use IntelliJ Idea Ultimate at work.  And for personal stuff I like VS Code.

Comment: I didn't watch the video, but Webflow sounds like a WYSIWYG.  I stay as far away from them as possible.

Answer (score 2):

Well, there are two approaches here:

**1. Online Websites creators**

There are many online tools for creating websites. The most popular are:

1. [Unbounce](https://unbounce.com/br/)
2. [Wix](http://wix.com.br/)

These tools allow you to create websites without edit any line of code.

**1. Professional web development:**

when I started working with HTML and JavaScript, in 2006, I started with the Windows Notepad, and this helped me a lot to memorize all the tags. Some years ago, I worked with Adobe Dreamweaver as well.

Today, the most popular editors among front-end engineers are [MS Visual Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) and [Atom](https://atom.io/). These are free/open source and excellent editors. There are many other popular editors as well. I used **Visual Code** and **Atom** for a long time. Today I'm using [Webstorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/) from Jetbrains. Webstorm is a very powerful JavaScript IDE (it's free for college students).

Most of the front-end developers use UI frameworks to develop UI elements such as Buttons, Forms, Boxes, etc. [Twitter Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/) is the most famous UI framework today, however, there is a bunch of UI frameworks available. You can also develop UI elements only coding native HTML and CSS for styling.

This is just the tip of the iceberg. There are many great tools available on the web.